# Insert attribute into List attribute in Java

Tags: java, list, testing, properties, attributes

I have a doubt about an implementation which I don't know if is correct or I am committing a crime. I have a test class with 2 class attributes, a custom object and a List of these objects. For each test, the object is reset and inserted into the list and I think it is smell very bad. Is this correct or maybe it can cause problems to me?

```
public class TestingClass {

private List<CustomObject> objects;

private CustomObject object;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    objects = new ArrayList<>();
    object = new CustomObject();
}

@Test
public void firstTest() {
    object.setProperty("n1");
    objects.add(object);

    assert(objects.get(0).getProperty().equals("n1");
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The purpose of this is that you have a clean state for each test. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I think the problem can be in the fact that I am inserting a class attribute into another class attribute, it seems rare

Comment: Why should that be a problem?